# ui:include inside tabview with another ui:include

Tags: jsf, include, facelets, tabview

Using Tomcat 7.0.34, Primefaces 3.5 and mojarra 2.1.25
I have the following file "client.xhtml":

```
  <ui:composition template="/templates/Template.xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <ui:define name="template_conteudo">
  <h:form id="formDadosCliente">
  <ui:include src="/client.inc"/>
  </h:form>
  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
```

The file client.inc (which is a normal xhtml, and is use in several xhtml files) is the following: (simplified)

```
<ui:fragment xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
             xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
             xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">    
    <p:tabView>
        <p:tab title="Client Info">
            // Client info stuff
        </p:tab>

        <ui:include src="clientBilling.inc"/>
    </p:tabView>
</ui:fragment>
```

and the "clientBilling.inc": (which I use in several other xhtml files)

```
<p:tab title="other tab">
</p:tab>

<p:tab title="another tab">
</p:tab>
```

The tabs from the "clientBilling.inc" are not showing, but the content is shown if I take it off the p:tabView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stumpled across this old question with no answer and i like to try...

I get this working when adding a few lines in clientBilling.inc:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <p:tab title="other tab">
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab title="another tab">
  </p:tab>

</ui:composition>
```